# Mouseclick + mousemove / console.log respond 200 times when hover a div

Tags: jquery, css, click, mousemove

I got some squares when you click on the total div called selector and drag the mouse over the squares, the square you hover will get the color you picked with the color picker.

Now when you picked a color and click on 1 of the squares and drag your mouse. You will see in the console.log that every div you hover respond 200 times. That makes your website very laggy.

How can I make it like everytime I hover 1 of the divs it only respond 1 time.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/4o9t42b8/

Steps:
**Open the console. Pick a color. And click and drag your mouse.**

HTML:

```
Pick color:
<input class="getColor" type="color" name="favcolor">
<div class="selector">
    <div class="one1"></div>
    <div class="one2"></div>
    <div class="one3"></div>
    <div class="one4"></div>
    <div class="one5"></div>
    <div class="one6"></div>
    <div class="one7"></div>
    <div class="one8"></div>
    <div class="one9"></div>
    <div class="one10"></div>
    <div class="one11"></div>
    <div class="one12"></div>
    <div class="one13"></div>
    <div class="one14"></div>
    <div class="one15"></div>
    <div class="one16"></div>
    <div class="one17"></div>
    <div class="one18"></div>
    <div class="one19"></div>
    <div class="one20"></div>
    <div class="one21"></div>
    <div class="one22"></div>
    <div class="one23"></div>
    <div class="one24"></div>
    <div class="one25"></div>
    <div class="one26"></div>
    <div class="one27"></div>
    <div class="one28"></div>
    <div class="one29"></div>
    <div class="one30"></div>
    <div class="one31"></div>
    <div class="one32"></div>
    <div class="one33"></div>
    <div class="one34"></div>
    <div class="one35"></div>
    <div class="one36"></div>
    <div class="one37"></div>
    <div class="one38"></div>
    <div class="one39"></div>
    <div class="one40"></div>
</div>
<div class="rotation">
    <div class="order one1"></div>
    <div class="order one2"></div>
    <div class="order one3"></div>
    <div class="order one4"></div>
    <div class="order one5"></div>
    <div class="order one6"></div>
    <div class="order one7"></div>
    <div class="order one8"></div>
    <div class="order one9"></div>
    <div class="order one10"></div>
    <div class="order one11"></div>
    <div class="order one12"></div>
    <div class="order one13"></div>
    <div class="order one14"></div>
    <div class="order one15"></div>
    <div class="order one16"></div>
    <div class="order one17"></div>
    <div class="order one18"></div>
    <div class="order one19"></div>
    <div class="order one20"></div>
    <div class="order one21"></div>
    <div class="order one22"></div>
    <div class="order one23"></div>
    <div class="order one24"></div>
    <div class="order one25"></div>
    <div class="order one26"></div>
    <div class="order one27"></div>
    <div class="order one28"></div>
    <div class="order one29"></div>
    <div class="order one30"></div>
    <div class="order one31"></div>
    <div class="order one32"></div>
    <div class="order one33"></div>
    <div class="order one34"></div>
    <div class="order one35"></div>
    <div class="order one36"></div>
    <div class="order one37"></div>
    <div class="order one38"></div>
    <div class="order one39"></div>
    <div class="order one40"></div>
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var clicking = false;
$(".getColor").change(function () {
    var getColor = $(".getColor").val();
    var color = getColor;
    $('.selector').mousedown(function () {
        clicking = true;
        $('.clickstatus').text('mousedown');
        $(".selector > div").click(function () {
            var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
            $(".empty").text(myClass);
            var getVal = $(".empty").text();
            $("." + getVal + "").css("background", color);
            console.log(getVal);
        });
    });

    $('.selector').mouseup(function () {
        clicking = false;
    });
    $('.selector').mousemove(function () {
        if (clicking) {
            $(".selector > div").hover(function () {
                if (clicking) {
                    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
                    $(".empty").text(myClass);
                    var getVal = $(".empty").text();
                    $("." + getVal + "").css("background", color);
                    console.log(getVal);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $(".selector").mouseleave(function () {
        clicking = false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.selector {
    width: 400px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    cursor:crosshair;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.rotation {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}
.selector > div {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background:white;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.order {
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.empty {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I can't test it, but you might be looking for a `debounce` function like those in lodash and underscore.

Comment: each time you pick another color, you add a new event listener without removing the old ones and each time you move your mouse over you div, you add other event listeners to cpature hover (and note that you add really a lot of them since mousemove gets triggered a lot when moving your mouse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you bind some events inside other events (like inside mousedown) you keep binding div click event.

```
$(".selector > div").click(function () {}
```

and inside mouse move you also bind the hover event every time the mouse moves

```
$(".selector > div").hover(function () {
```

And you bind all of that inside the 'change' event from the color picker;

You don't need to do that just set flags to keep track of what state you are in / what's important and only set the events handlers once.

```
var color, clicking = false;
$(".getColor").change(function () {
  color = $(".getColor").val();
}):

$('.selector').mousedown(function () {
  clicking = true;
  $('.clickstatus').text('mousedown');
});
$('.selector').mouseup(function () {
  clicking = false;
});
$(".selector").mouseleave(function () {
  clicking = false;
});

$(".selector > div").click(function () {
  var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
  $(".empty").text(myClass);
  var getVal = $(".empty").text();
  $("." + getVal + "").css("background", color);
  console.log(getVal);
});

$(".selector > div").hover(function () {
  if (clicking) {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".empty").text(myClass);
    var getVal = $(".empty").text();
    $("." + getVal + "").css("background", color);
    console.log(getVal);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment I think you should remake your JS:

```
var clicking = false;
var color = "black";
$('.selector').mousedown(function () {
    clicking = true;
});
$('.selector').mouseup(function () {
    clicking = false;
});
$(".selector > div").click(function () {
    $("."+this.className).css("background", color);
    console.log(this.className);
});
$(".selector").mouseleave(function () {
    clicking = false;
});
$(".getColor").change(function () {
    color = $(".getColor").val();
});
$(".selector > div").on("mouseover", function () {
    if (clicking) {
        $("."+this.className).css("background", color);
        console.log(this.className);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pv9pno5/1/)

Not to mention that I really do not know why you are doing this:

```
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
$(".empty").text(myClass);
var getVal = $(".empty").text();
$("." + getVal + "").css("background", color);
console.log(getVal);
```

Which means: find this by jquery so we can get attribute class, find another element where we can store this value, let's get that value again by finding that element again and finally find by classname we now (again have), while className is perfectly accessible from `this.className`